# Xamarin DependencyService vs Device.OnPlatform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

Would someone be able to explain the difference between using a DependencyService versus the Device.OnPlatform feature in an Xamarin PCL project? I have a basic overview of what they both are from reading the documentation on Xamarin but I am still a little lost on what exactly the difference is. They seem like they provide the same functionality but maybe I just have a completely wrong understanding of these features.

Answer (score 2):

`DependencyService` allows you to pull and access the native implementation for a particular contract from a platform-specific library into your cross-platform library.

While, `Device.OnPlatform` allows you to define different actions for each native platform in the cross-platform library itself.

If you need to define platform-specific behavior/action(s) that interact with native OS framework(s) (such as Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS etc.) - then you use `DependencyService` to allow access to this behavior in shared code. *For example: you can use it to implement and use a device-status-helper in your portable library.*

If you need to define platform-specific behavior/action(s) that don't need to interact with native frameworks but just shared ones (such as Xamarin.Forms, RESX etc.) - then you use `Device.OnPlatform` to define them in shared code. *For example: You can use it to define platform-specific style(s) for a forms button. (can be defined in both C# and XAML)*.

Comment: Ok that makes a little more sense now. So to make sure I am understanding this right, say I am using James Montemagno's Media.Plugin in my PCL or just any API really that accesses some sort of hardware on a device. I would use DependencyService to implement the API on each native platform?

Comment: Or would it be the other way around, if I had some API that is specific to Android, I would use DependencyService to use that API in my PCL?

Comment: Usually a contract/interface is defined in such a case. You will then implement it to access the API specific to android and register it using `DependencyService`. In your PCL, you can then resolve it using `DependencyService` to access your implementation.